# How to detect text change or href change of an anchor tag in js/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to detect text change or href change of an anchor tag in js/jquery

i've tried plenty of event handlers in both jquery and vanilla js but it doesn't seem to be working for me, any simply/clever suggestions? am i missing something?

i made sure that those event handlers doesn't really support anchor tags before posting, i'm not sure what i am missing here

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

Comment: where is the code you tried so far ??

Comment: There is no native handler for this, why are you trying to listen to href changes? This seems to be a case of a X/Y problem

Comment: When do you expect the text or `href` attribute to be changed?

Answer (score 1):

The text inside an anchor and its `href` link don't change spontaneously. There is always some javascript code that's listening to some event in order to change it. You should detect where this listener is, and to do this you can use google developer tools.

Open google chrome, go to your page and click on the top left arrow, select the element and then click on the "Event Listeners" tab. A menu with all the event listeners will appear.

Once you detected where's the function that's changing your anchor, so just append some extra code to it in order to execute actions.